# How to keep track of creation index when creating a list of functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

My code looks something like this:

```
list.add(TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                int temp = index;
                print(temp);
              },
              child: Text(myText),
));
```

However, when I put this list in a widget and try to click on any of the TextButtons, I get the last index of the loop.

How could I make it so that when I click on one of the TextButton, I get its right index?

Here is the full function,

```
  List<TableRow> generateTables() {
    List<TableRow> list = [];

    int index = 0;

    for (Map element in exerciseList) {
      String exName = element["name"];
      Icon? icon = correspIcon(element);
      list.add(
        TableRow(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                int temp = index;
                print(temp);
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size.zero,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              ),
              child: Text(
                exName,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "ArialRounded",
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white.withAlpha(240)),
              ),
            ),
            icon ?? const SizedBox()
          ],
        ),
      );

      index++;
    }
    return list;
  }
```

What I want to happen is that if I click  on the n-th TextButton in the list, the index returned is n-1.

Thanks a lot if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

use this to get to the index value of the selected element
the above code does not work because the index value always holds the last element

```
  List<TableRow> generateTables() {
    List<TableRow> list = [];

     for (var i=0; i<exerciseList.length; i++) {
        final Map element= exerciseList[i];
      String exName = element["name"];
      Icon? icon = correspIcon(element);
      list.add(
        TableRow(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                int temp = i;
                print(temp);
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size.zero,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              ),
              child: Text(
                exName,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "ArialRounded",
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white.withAlpha(240)),
              ),
            ),
            icon ?? const SizedBox()
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return list;
  }
```